# Remove Padding in JQuery UI tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, layout

I want to move the text more closer to left...

[image: I want to move the text more closer to left]

ok with the shown picture above, I want to override the padding of my jquery-ui-tab page. I tried already the code below but seems not to be working.

```
$(".ui-tabs.panel").css('padding','0px');
```

now how can I make this possible?,

**NOTE**: I want a css or jquery override and i don't want to alter any jquery-ui css files

Comment: Have you tried `$(".ui-tabs.panel").css('padding','0px !important');`?

Comment: @PavelStaseljun still not working (ノД`)・゜・。

Comment: You sure that this is caused by `.ui-tabs.panel` padding? Can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: @PavelStaseljun I can't even make it on jsfiddle, i can't create tabs.. can you help me thank you http://jsfiddle.net/laupkram/Pctm4/

Comment: Works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/Pctm4/2/

Comment: @PavelStaseljun now its working! thank you.. please post your answer i gonna accept it hehe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with plain css; try this for example:

Include this in your main stylesheet:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
    padding: 1em 1.4em 1em 0;
}
```

Comment: I had to add !important to get this to take in one odd case, but it works well.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but this works nicely.  Assuming you have a containing div with a class of 'style-tabs' like so:

```
<div id="tabs" class="style-tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="ajax/MyTab.php">My Tab</a></li>
<li><a href="ajax/MyTab2.php">My Tab 2</a></li>
<ul>
</div>

This CSS works nicely (setting a negative margin)...

.style-tabs li a { 
    margin: -0.3em; 
    padding: 0; 
 }
```

Comment: Hmm, that was useful to me, but by putting it on the div on the content that goes in the tab,